# Is there Session.Abandon() asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In Asp.net WebForms there is an event called Session_End() in global.asax, whenever session is timeout or you call Session.Abandon() this event handler is executed, i need to have similar kind of behavior in asp.net Core, is it possible?

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question. Hard to answer!

Comment: Have you tried Session.Clear()?

Comment: I need to capture the event when session is automatically timeout, is there any why to capture that event or is there any event at all?

Comment: I noticed that the `Configure` function runs on `Startup.cs` when a `Session` is created.
I used this method to create a way to use `HttpContext` in classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815975/6778726

Answer (score 15):

You could clear the session by simply calling:

`HttpContext.Session.Clear();`

Comment: This will cause the `Session` to be **empty** but not **deleted** or **abandoned**.

Comment: Then what if we need to do Abandon in .Net Core 3.1?

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html?highlight=session) cover most of this. The session timeout is set like this:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});
```

But since it exists is a cookie, the cookie also has an expiration date. So if `IdleTimeout` expires, the session expires. If the cookie expires, the session is gone. If the cookie is deleted, the session is gone.

Calling `Session.Clear()` removes the contents of the session, but keeps the session intact (aka, the cookie isn't deleted) as described in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/440c6e43e185594e83b33f280e45868b58199926/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/ISession.cs).

Comment: in Asp.net WebForms there is something called Seesion_End() in global.asax, whenever session is timeout or you call Session.Abandon() this event handler is executed, i need to have similar kind of behaviour in asp.net Core, is it possible?

Comment: So there is no way to programmatically invalidate a session e.g. when the user is using a logout button? What would be the recommended way to invalidate a session apart from setting the idle timeout very low. Also what value can be checked to assure that the timeout actually invalidated the session? It somehow seems that the Session implementation in .net Core is not fully implemented, or I'm missing something here.

Comment: @vm370 As mentioned by Tratcher above, the recommended way to invalidate a session from code is to call `Session.Clear()`. There's some further discussion here: [Session Issue 27](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/27)