# HttpContext.Session.Abandon() doesn't work in MVC core. Session.clear doesn't log my user out

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I get an error that says "ISession does not contain a definition for 'Abandon' and no accessible extension method 'Abandon' accepting a first argument of type 'ISession' could be found".

I have tried using session.clear but even after logging out if I open the website the user is logged in.

This is the error I get

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there Session.Abandon() asp.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018508/is-there-session-abandon-asp-net-core)

Comment: @PeterB  The question you have referred doesn't answer my question as I have tried with session.clear too but still it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my session is being stored in cookies and not getting cleared/deleted when used session.clear()

so I've used this and it seems to work like a charm.

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)

        {
            if (cookie == ".AspNetCore.Session")
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
        }
```

Comment: In case cookie name has been changed, this takes the name from configuration: `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(_sessionOptions.Value.Cookie.Name)` where `_sessionOptions` is injected as `IOptions<SessionOptions>`

Comment: You can improve your answer with LINQ, revise my edits for more details

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have implemented Session in my ASP .NET CORE project:

Create a SessionTimeout filter:

```
public class SessionTimeout : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Session == null ||!context.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("UserID", out byte[] val))
        {
            context.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Pages",
                    action = "SessionTimeout"
                }));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Register this filter in your Startup.cs:

In your ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);               
            });
```

In your Configure add:

```
app.UseSession();
```

And finally decorate your class/method with your filter like:

```
    [SessionTimeout]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
```

To destroy your session based on Logout event from your View:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", new { controller = "Pages" });
        }
```

Comment: Tnx a ton Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Session.Clear() wasn't working for me on my live site in the Controller for my Account/Logout page.

I found out that setting a href of /Account/Logout/ was the problem. I changed my links to /Account/Logout.

If you're having Session problems in .NET Core 3.1 then try this. It may also account for why I couldn't get Cookie Authentication to work - I gave up in the end and switched to using Sessions.